# PostGIS ST_AsGeoJson makes geometry invalid

Tags: postgis, postgresql

For the following SQL, I create a GeoJSON from a valid geometry, which makes it invalid:

```
select st_asgeojson(geometry, 6), st_isvalid(geometry), st_isvalid(st_geomfromgeojson(st_asgeojson(geometry, 6)))
from bd_region
where id = 310100;
```

the output:

```
{some GeoJSON}, true, false
```

the output JSON is here:
https://jsonblob.com/c62204c1-03f1-11e8-8467-f5eea275e9a5

After a search I found that may due to precision reason. How can I fix it?

```
  [
    [
      121.412516,
      31.244891
    ],
    [
      121.41456,
      31.243229
    ],
    [
      121.41456,
      31.243229
    ],
    [
      121.412516,
      31.244891
    ]
  ],
```

Comment: Have you tried using ST_MakeValid(st_geomfromgeojson(st_asgeojson(geometry, 6)))

Comment: did you try change the precision from `6` to something else ? the default value is `15` by good reason (e.g. to avoid these problems).

Comment: What was your solution to this?

Comment: @LiamG This does not solve the issue when the result needs to be a geojson string. also running into the same problem moving geometries between databases like BigQuery where geojson is the quickest way of parsing geographies